# req.params.value is undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js

In my Node js Application, am using Angular js for data binding.
Am using ng-controller, inside which I use an http service to get data from the database.

On the button click event am calling clickedbutton function,where I pass a value to the service.

HomeController.js

```
app.controller('BasicHomeController', function ($scope, $filter,$http) {

    $scope.clickedbutton=function(value){

    $http.get('/getData/'+value)
      .then(successCallback, errorCallback);  

  };
);
```

However am not able to get the service value from the browser using req.params. It gives undefined value.

app.js

```
app.get('/getData/:value', function(req,res){

    var reqid = req.params.value; //It gives reqid as undefined

});
```

Comment: Are you using express 3 or 4?

Comment: Are you sure the `value` isn't undefined on Angular side already? Try adding a `console.log(value)` on the line before the $http request

Comment: Hi thank you,Am using Express4.

Comment: Value in Angular side is not undefined. Am getting the values in console.